# Vue-cli correct processing of <link rel="preload/prefetch">

Tags: vue.js, webpack, assets, preload, vue-cli-3

How is it possible to make webpack correctly process assets in `<link rel="preload/prefetch">` tags?

For example, when using inside `/public/index.html`

```html
<link rel="preload" href="@/assets/fonts/myfont.woff2" as="font" crossorigin>
```

webpack should fingerprint the file and copy to `/fonts` just as it would do in case of

```css
url('~@/assets/fonts/myfont.woff2'); /* inside css */
```

Resulting in

```html
<link rel="preload" href="/fonts/myfont.$HASH$.woff2" as="font" crossorigin>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solution:

```html
<link rel="preload" href="<%= require('@/assets/fonts/myfont.woff2') %>" as="font" crossorigin>
```

Be aware that if you for example want to

```html
<link rel="icon" href="<%= require('@/assets/favicon.png') %>" type="image/png">
```

webpack will probably url-inline that favicon (if it's small enought) according to default webpack config, that vue-cli generates for you.